# Error "The only valid numeric escape in strict mode is '\0" for styled components in Material-UI (MUI)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the numeric quote for the quotation marks. However, I am getting this error:

> 'The only valid numeric escape in strict mode is '\0`

The code is below:

```
export const Title = styled(Typography)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: "black",
  "&:before": {
    content: "\201c",
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two backslashes instead of one to escape the Unicode content, since [ESLint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESLint) disallows it.

So change `"\201c"` to  `"\\201c"`

```js
export const Title = styled(Typography)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: "black",
  "&:before": {
    content: "\\201c",
  },
}));
```